# Sum of two Time columns

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, date-time

There are two calculated columns that display times of two date columns.
I want to sum those two "time" columns. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Example:
column 1: 16:35
column 2: 14:00

So, result should be 30:35.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date calculations go from `23:59` to `00:00`

So

```
=TEXT( Time(16,35,0)+Time(14,0,0) , "hh:mm" )
```

will produce

```
06:35
```

#### Let's take different values to examine edge-cases

What should **16:35 + 14:35** do?

To get to **`30:70`** you have to count hours and minutes

But I can't imagine any use case for that

You probably want the **Duration** result: **`31:10`**

#### 16:35 + 14:35 = 31:10

So you have to:

- count the minutes to a HH:MM notation
- convert the MM to a Number
- convert the HH to a Number
- add the two hours count to the HH Number
- create a TEXT string making it *look like* a hh:mm notation

... that is going to be long Formula..

#### Luckily I have a (private) app to build **and merge** Formulas:

[image]

(*SharePoint is not typed, so it doesn't really care about Text or Numbers, it will proces "1" as 1*)

---

#### Your Formula

So with 2 basefields H1 and H2 your Formula is:

```
=HOUR(H1)+HOUR(H2)+TEXT(TIME(0,MINUTE(H1)+MINUTE(H2),0),"hh")
 &":"
 &MID(TEXT(TIME(0,MINUTE(H1)+MINUTE(H2),0),"hh:mm"),4,2)
```

The MID(  hh:mm) is required because TEXT(n,"mm") converts to Months, not Minutes

#### The Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much on your time and effort! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Beside great post by Danny, I solved problem by this:

1st, I separated hours and minutes from columns into 4 columns.
example: column 1 is 12:10 and with `=Left([column 1],2)` I get hours and with formula `=Right(Left([column 1],5),2)` I get  minutes.
2nd, I summed hours and than multiplied them with 60, to get value minutes and summed this value with sum of minutes' columns.
3rd, after this I had one column that represented time in minutes. I divided it with 60 in one column, output calculated column type is number with 0 decimals, by this I get whole hours, in another calculated column I used formula `=MOD([minute column],60)`. this was for minutes. Again number type with 0 decimals is output calculated column.
4th combined column of hours with column of minutes with **Concatenate**.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(hours,"0"),":",TEXT(minutes,"0"))
```

I had to use TEXT because my data was in number with 0 decimals and Concatenate formula would not work if I left data like that. So I had to convert it to text.

Comment: All roads lead to Rome... Note that ``"x"&"y"&"z"`` does the same as the concatenate function.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
=TEXT(Column1+Column2,"h:mm")
```

This will return Sum in hours and minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this formula cannot be, not in this format, implemented to my request. Due to fact formula would calculated only until 24:00 or 00AM if result is higher, I get error response #VALUE!